# Enum datatype conversion to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

How do I convert an enum datatype from int to string?

Here is my code below

```
public class Users_Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(string), ErrorMessage = "{0} Opps")]
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my `Title` enum:

```
public enum Title
{
    Mr, Mrs, Miss, Chief 
}
```

I get the error

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Int32'.

I know enums are strongly type and have a value of int, and in my database its `nvarchar(20)`

How do I convert it?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you please explain why must be a string?

Comment: An enum for an honorific seems a bad idea since they are so often optional - some people do not like to say and if their title was `Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea, Breaker of Chains, Mother of Dragons`  well, you missed that one

Comment: @TânNguyễn because the values in the database are of string. By the way, i watched your videos on youtube ? Great vids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide you an example that you can try but *it's just a quick solution* since you didn't design database structure.

Enum item:

```
public enum Title
{
    Mr, 
    Mrs, 
    Miss, 
    Chief 
}
```

By default, `Title.Mr` should have the default value `0`, `Mrs` has value `1`..., same to the orthers.

If you have 256 items or lower in the enum, you could try:

```
public enum Title : byte
{
    Mr = 0, 
    Mrs = 1, 
    Miss = 2, 
    Chief = 3
}
```

`Title.Mr` still has value `0`.

The entity:

```
public class Users_Accounts
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueID { get; set; }

    //You can change the returned type of `Title` property from `Title` to `string` here
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

The model:

```
public class AddUserViewModel
{
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

When updating to database, you need to convert enum to a string:

```
public IActionResult AddUser(AddUserViewModel model)
{
    // title contains value like: 0, 1, 2... as string
    string title = ((int)model.Title).ToString();

    var user = new Users_Accounts
    {
        AccountID = ...
        UniqueID = ...
        Title = title,
        First_Name = model.First_Name,
        Last_Name = model.Last_Name
    };

    _dbContext.UserAccounts.Add(user);

    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When you get some user, you can convert the `Title` as string to enum:

```
var user = _dbContext.UserAccounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountID == 1);
Title userTitle = (Title)Convert.ToInt32(user.Title);
```

`userTitle` would return `Title.Mr` or `Title.Mrs`...

**NOTE:** If you decide to use

```
public enum Title : byte {}
```

You need to change `Convert.ToInt32` to `Convert.ToByte` instead.

Comment: Must say, this is quite intelligent coding and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also found this online, and though its MVC 5 changing View.Bag to View["Data"] it works

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/